# How to shift logo (.png / .jpg) to center of navbar when the screen gets smaller for Material UI template?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, responsive-design, navbar

I'm using an app bar with responsive menu template from Material UI. The template came with an original logo that is one of the MUI icons. I need to replace this MUI icon (AdbIcon in the code) with my actual logo, a .png/.jpg file.

But here's the before and after.

Before:

[image]

After:

[image]

How do I shift the logo to center of navbar when the screen gets smaller to make the site more responsive?

I have made some minor amendments and here's my code.

```
import { useState } from "react";

import { Fragment } from "react";
import { Outlet, Link } from "react-router-dom";

import AppBar from "@mui/material/AppBar";
import Box from "@mui/material/Box";
import Toolbar from "@mui/material/Toolbar";
import IconButton from "@mui/material/IconButton";
import Typography from "@mui/material/Typography";
import Menu from "@mui/material/Menu";
import MenuIcon from "@mui/icons-material/Menu";
import Container from "@mui/material/Container";
import Avatar from "@mui/material/Avatar";
import Button from "@mui/material/Button";
import Tooltip from "@mui/material/Tooltip";
import MenuItem from "@mui/material/MenuItem";
import AdbIcon from "@mui/icons-material/Adb";
import "./navigation-bar.styles.scss";

const pages = ["Page 1", "Page 2", "Page 3"];
const settings = ["Profile", "My purchases", "Logout"];

const NavigationBar = () => {
  const [anchorElNav, setAnchorElNav] = useState(null);
  const [anchorElUser, setAnchorElUser] = useState(null);

  const handleOpenNavMenu = (event) => {
    setAnchorElNav(event.currentTarget);
  };
  const handleOpenUserMenu = (event) => {
    setAnchorElUser(event.currentTarget);
  };

  const handleCloseNavMenu = () => {
    setAnchorElNav(null);
  };

  const handleCloseUserMenu = () => {
    setAnchorElUser(null);
  };

  return (
    <Fragment>
      <AppBar position="fixed">
        <Container maxWidth="xl">
          <Toolbar disableGutters>

// This is the logo I want to add.
            <Link>
              <img
                className="nav-logo"
             src="https://cdn.dribbble.com/userupload/3158903/file/original-3f5abe8b99ff4ba4626ddf6660115182.jpg?compress=1&resize=752x"
                alt="Porousway Logo"
              />
            </Link>

// This is the original logo
            <AdbIcon sx={{ display: { xs: "none", md: "flex" }, mr: 1 }} />
            <Typography
              variant="h6"
              noWrap
              component="a"
              href="/"
              sx={{
                mr: 2,
                display: { xs: "none", md: "flex" },
                fontFamily: "monospace",
                fontWeight: 700,
                letterSpacing: ".3rem",
                color: "inherit",
                textDecoration: "none",
              }}
            >
              LOGO
            </Typography>
            <Box sx={{ flexGrow: 1, display: { xs: "flex", md: "none" } }}>
              <IconButton
                size="large"
                aria-label="account of current user"
                aria-controls="menu-appbar"
                aria-haspopup="true"
                onClick={handleOpenNavMenu}
                color="inherit"
              >
                <MenuIcon />
              </IconButton>
              <Menu
                id="menu-appbar"
                anchorEl={anchorElNav}
                anchorOrigin={{
                  vertical: "bottom",
                  horizontal: "left",
                }}
                keepMounted
                transformOrigin={{
                  vertical: "top",
                  horizontal: "left",
                }}
                open={Boolean(anchorElNav)}
                onClose={handleCloseNavMenu}
                sx={{
                  display: { xs: "block", md: "none" },
                }}
              >
                {pages.map((page) => (
                  <MenuItem key={page} onClick={handleCloseNavMenu}>
                    <Typography textAlign="center">{page}</Typography>
                  </MenuItem>
                ))}
              </Menu>
            </Box>
            <AdbIcon sx={{ display: { xs: "flex", md: "none" }, mr: 1 }} />
            <Typography
              variant="h5"
              noWrap
              component="a"
              href=""
              sx={{
                mr: 2,
                display: { xs: "flex", md: "none" },
                flexGrow: 1,
                fontFamily: "monospace",
                fontWeight: 700,
                letterSpacing: ".3rem",
                color: "inherit",
                textDecoration: "none",
              }}
            >
              LOGO
            </Typography>
            <Box sx={{ flexGrow: 1, display: { xs: "none", md: "flex" } }}>
              {pages.map((page) => (
                <Button
                  key={page}
                  onClick={handleCloseNavMenu}
                  sx={{ my: 2, color: "white", display: "block" }}
                >
                  {page}
                </Button>
              ))}
            </Box>
            <Box sx={{ flexGrow: 0 }}>
              <Tooltip title="Open settings">
                <IconButton onClick={handleOpenUserMenu} sx={{ p: 0 }}>
                  <Avatar alt="Remy Sharp" src="/static/images/avatar/2.jpg" />
                </IconButton>
              </Tooltip>
              <Menu
                sx={{ mt: "45px" }}
                id="menu-appbar"
                anchorEl={anchorElUser}
                anchorOrigin={{
                  vertical: "top",
                  horizontal: "right",
                }}
                keepMounted
                transformOrigin={{
                  vertical: "top",
                  horizontal: "right",
                }}
                open={Boolean(anchorElUser)}
                onClose={handleCloseUserMenu}
              >
                {settings.map((setting) => (
                  <MenuItem key={setting} onClick={handleCloseUserMenu}>
                    <Typography textAlign="center">{setting}</Typography>
                  </MenuItem>
                ))}
              </Menu>
            </Box>
          </Toolbar>
        </Container>
      </AppBar>

      <Outlet />
    </Fragment>
  );
};

export default NavigationBar;
```

The original can be found [here](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-app-bar/#ResponsiveAppBar.js).

Edit: To include "LOGO" in code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the example in the documentation, you can see that there are actually two separate "logos" and they just hide one or the other based on the screen size.  You could do the same thing:

```
// excerpted return:

    return (
        <AppBar position="static">
            <Container maxWidth="xl">
                <Toolbar disableGutters>
                    {/* YOUR LOGO HERE FOR MD+ SCREENS */}
                    <Link
                        href="#"
                        underline="none"
                        sx={{
                            mr: 2,
                            display: { xs: 'none', md: 'flex' },
                        }}
                    >
                        <img
                            className="nav-logo"
                            src="https://cdn.dribbble.com/userupload/3158903/file/original-3f5abe8b99ff4ba4626ddf6660115182.jpg?compress=1&resize=752x"
                            alt="Porousway Logo"
                            width="40"
                            height="40"
                        />
                    </Link>
                    {/* END LOGO */}

                    <Box sx={{ flexGrow: 1, display: { xs: 'flex', md: 'none' } }}>
                        <IconButton
                            size="large"
                            aria-label="account of current user"
                            aria-controls="menu-appbar"
                            aria-haspopup="true"
                            onClick={handleOpenNavMenu}
                            color="inherit"
                        >
                            <MenuIcon />
                        </IconButton>
                        <Menu
                            id="menu-appbar"
                            anchorEl={anchorElNav}
                            anchorOrigin={{
                                vertical: 'bottom',
                                horizontal: 'left',
                            }}
                            keepMounted
                            transformOrigin={{
                                vertical: 'top',
                                horizontal: 'left',
                            }}
                            open={Boolean(anchorElNav)}
                            onClose={handleCloseNavMenu}
                            sx={{
                                display: { xs: 'block', md: 'none' },
                            }}
                        >
                            {pages.map((page) => (
                                <MenuItem key={page} onClick={handleCloseNavMenu}>
                                    <Typography textAlign="center">{page}</Typography>
                                </MenuItem>
                            ))}
                        </Menu>
                    </Box>
                    {/* YOUR LOGO HERE FOR SMALL SCREENS */}
                    <Link
                        href="#"
                        underline="none"
                        sx={{
                            mr: 2,
                            display: { xs: 'flex', md: 'none' },
                            width: '100%',
                            justifyContent: 'center',
                        }}
                    >
                        <img
                            className="nav-logo"
                            src="https://cdn.dribbble.com/userupload/3158903/file/original-3f5abe8b99ff4ba4626ddf6660115182.jpg?compress=1&resize=752x"
                            alt="Porousway Logo"
                            width="40"
                            height="40"
                        />
                    </Link>
                    {/* END LOGO */}
                    <Box sx={{ flexGrow: 1, display: { xs: 'none', md: 'flex' } }}>
                        {pages.map((page) => (
                            <Button
                                key={page}
                                onClick={handleCloseNavMenu}
                                sx={{ my: 2, color: 'white', display: 'block' }}
                            >
                                {page}
                            </Button>
                        ))}
                    </Box>

                    <Box sx={{ flexGrow: 0 }}>
                        <Tooltip title="Open settings">
                            <IconButton onClick={handleOpenUserMenu} sx={{ p: 0 }}>
                                <Avatar alt="Remy Sharp" src="/static/images/avatar/2.jpg" />
                            </IconButton>
                        </Tooltip>
                        <Menu
                            sx={{ mt: '45px' }}
                            id="menu-appbar"
                            anchorEl={anchorElUser}
                            anchorOrigin={{
                                vertical: 'top',
                                horizontal: 'right',
                            }}
                            keepMounted
                            transformOrigin={{
                                vertical: 'top',
                                horizontal: 'right',
                            }}
                            open={Boolean(anchorElUser)}
                            onClose={handleCloseUserMenu}
                        >
                            {settings.map((setting) => (
                                <MenuItem key={setting} onClick={handleCloseUserMenu}>
                                    <Typography textAlign="center">{setting}</Typography>
                                </MenuItem>
                            ))}
                        </Menu>
                    </Box>
                </Toolbar>
            </Container>
        </AppBar>
```